# How to Get Param Id from URL in express/mongo/mongoose on server side, axios/react/redux on client side

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, parameters, axios

I am having some trouble with get the param from the url. I use Express(4.16.3) on the server side, and using Axios to make the request. But I couldn't seem to get the param from the url in Express.

Here is my code:

on my Route.js in Express

```
app.get('/api/surveys/:surveyId', (req, res, next) => {
    var id = req.params.surveyId;
    console.log(req.params);
    // it gets  params {surveyId: ':surverId'}
    res.send('Hello World');
});
```

so instead of getting the actual id, it logs params: {surveyId: ':surveyId'}. I have been researching, but seems this is the correct way to do it. I also use axios to make the request:

in actions/index.js (I use react):

```
export const fetchOneSurvey = () => async dispatch => {
const res = await axios.get('/api/surveys/:surveyId');

dispatch({ type: FETCH_ONE_SURVEY, payload: res.data });};
```

Not sure if this is relevant: 
On the view page, instead of having http://localhost:3000/api/surveys/:surveyId, I have http://localhost:3000/surveys/:surveyId route set in React. When I go to http://localhost:3000/surveys/:surveyId,  it does console log (req.params) like I write in express, but I only get a string ':surveyId' is the params, not the actual id on the url.

Please anyone can help me? I have tried many different ways, but nothing seem working. I thank you all very much in advance.

===== Extra section ======
Here is my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config/keys');

require('./models/User');
require('./models/Survey');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/billingRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/surveyRoutes')(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

My survey model route js:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const Path = require('path-parser');
const { URL } = require('url');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const requireLogin = require('../middlewares/requireLogin');
const requireCredits = require('../middlewares/requireCredits');
const Mailer = require('../services/Mailer');
const surveyTemplate = require('../services/emailTemplates/surveyTemplate');

const Survey = mongoose.model('surveys');

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/api/surveys', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
        const surveys = await Survey.find({ _user: req.user.id }).select({
            recipients: false
        });

    res.send(surveys);
});

app.get('/api/surveys/:surveyId/:choice', (req, res) => {
    res.send('thanks for voting');
});

app.get('/api/surveys/:surveyId', (req, res, next) => {
    var id = req.params.surveyId;
    console.log(id);
    // it gets  params {surveyId: ':surverId'}
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.post('/api/surveys/webhooks', (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body);
    // res.send({});
    const p = new Path('/api/surveys/:surveyId/:choice');

    const test = _.chain(req.body)
        .map(({ email, url }) => {
            const match = p.test(new URL(url).pathname);
            if (match) {
                return {
                    email,
                    surveyId: match.surveyId,
                    choice: match.choice
                };
            }
        })
        .compact()
        .uniqBy('email', 'surveyId')
        .each(({ surveyId, email, choice }) => {
            Survey.updateOne(
                {
                    // have to add _ to keys as mongoDB rule, mongoose doensn't need.
                    _id: surveyId,
                    recipients: {
                        $elemMatch: { email: email, responded: false }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $inc: { [choice]: 1 },
                    $set: { 'recipients.$.responded': true },
                    lastResponded: new Date()
                }
            ).exec();
        })
        .value();

    console.log(test);

    res.send({});
});

app.post('/api/surveys', requireLogin, requireCredits, async (req, res) => {
    const { title, subject, body, recipients } = req.body;

    const survey = new Survey({
        // map(email => ({ email }) === map(email =>{ return {email: email}})
        title,
        body,
        subject,
        recipients: recipients
            .split(',')
            .map(email => ({ email: email.trim() })),
        _user: req.user.id,
        dateSent: Date.now()
    });

    // send an email
    const mailer = new Mailer(survey, surveyTemplate(survey));
    try {
        await mailer.send();
        await survey.save();
        req.user.credits -= 1;
        const user = await req.user.save();

        res.send(user);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(422).send(err);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: it logs {surveyId: ':surverId'} because you are printing req.params. you have to print id or req.params.surveyId to get the result you are expecting

Comment: even I print id, it still shows ':surveyId' , I logged req and it's still showing params {surveyId: ':surveyId'}... :(

Comment: @llads check my answer . i have posted it for debugging your problem. it could provide you some clues for resolving your issue. And i don't see a problem in the code you have posted. using react doesn't matter. You can test your route by triggering http request via browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting below details for debugging the issue**

**Note:** if you are using Windows OS, use command prompt for node project development. i have seen people using git bash for doing node project developments and it causes unnecessary issues

**Below are the steps for debugging**

1.Create a new directory`forexample test` and initialize it using `npm init`

2.Install express `npm install --save express`

3.Create a new file `for example index.js` and use below code

```
test/index.js

var express= require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/api/surveys/:surveyId",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.params.surveyId);
    res.send('Hello World');
});

var server= app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("port started at ",server.address().port);
})
```

4.Start the program `node index.js`

5.Trigger http request from browser http://localhost:3000/api/surveys/llads . The value `llads` can be accessed using the path param `surveyId` in the route

6.if you can see the below output in node console then the program is working as it should. And this has to work as described here.

[image]

if above steps yields expected output then i don't see any problem in your route code.

Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks @divine, I have followed your debug steps and got the result as expected. However, I don't have the route have in my index.js file in the actual project. I will add my index.js file and the survey model route js on my editing section. It would be great if you could take a look and see if you have any clues.

Comment: @llads having route logic in index.js might not resolve your issue. where is your full code?. i'll take a look at it

Comment: are you really sure that your request is reaching the route /api/surveys/:surveyId ? add additional console.log inside this method  to confirm if this particular route is triggered. Could you trigger this route via browser and test?

Comment: Ah, I got it, I tested out /api/surveys/:surveyId, it did grab the id. I guess then there is something wrong with my front-end routing. Thank you so much for solving this for me. I have a further question, but it's okay if you don't answer it as it's not quite related to this. I want to import the data from backend  /api/surveys/:surveyId to front end view /surveys/:surveyId, where I should look into that can wrong?

Comment: instead of sending res.send('Hello World');
 you can send json object like this res.send({"data":dataJSONObject}); . Express will automatically identify its a JSON object and set the contenttype to application/json in the response. You can get hold of this object in the axios .then callback. by this way you can send data from your server route to frontend code

Comment: @llads if you can't comprehend what i'm saying here, take a look at my article published in medium. it could provide you some insights. https://medium.com/@divine_rw/create-a-simple-web-application-api-setup-using-node-and-express-asap-a72e93f88768

Comment: Hi @divine, I am also having another issue if you don't mind take a look: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663215/how-to-load-previous-values-in-redux-from-field-on-screen-and-get-the-new-values) as you seems like an expert, thank you again, no worries if you don't have time.

Comment: @llads i'm not an expert ,but i have faced some number of problems :). i will go through your new question