# How to load previous values in Redux From Field on screen and get the new values as users enter them?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to load my previous values in Redux From Fields on screen and hoping to get new values from each fields as a user updates the values. I have tried couple different ways, like `onChange` or `initialValues` but so far I still have no luck to get it working:

Here is my code so far:

```
`import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SurveyField from './SurveyField';
import { fetchOneSurvey } from '../../actions';
import validateEmails from '../../utils/validateEmails';
import formFields from './formFields';

class SurveyEditForm extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const id = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
        this.props.fetchOneSurvey(id);
    }



renderFields() {
        return _.map(formFields, ({ label, name }) => {
            return (
                <Field
                    key={name}
                    component={SurveyField}
                    type="text"
                    label={label}
                    name={name}
                />
            );
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/*.handleSubmit is from reduxForm method*/}
                <form
                    onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(
                        this.props.onSurveySubmit
                    )}
                >
                    {this.renderFields()}

                    <Link to="/surveys" className="red btn-flat white-text">
                        Cancel
                    </Link>

                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="teal btn-flat right white-text"
                    >
                        Next
                        <i className="material-icons right">done</i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function validate(values) {
    const errors = {};
    errors.recipients = validateEmails(values.recipients || '');
    _.each(formFields, ({ name }) => {
        if (!values[name]) {
            errors[name] = 'You must provide a value';
        }
    });
    return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        surveyEdit: state.surveyEdit
    };
}

SurveyEditForm = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchOneSurvey })(SurveyEditForm);
SurveyEditForm = connect(state => ({
    initialValues: {
        title: this.props.surveyEdit.title
    }
}))(SurveyEditForm);

export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'surveyEditForm',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    enableReinitialize: true
})(SurveyEditForm);`
```

This currently gives me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'surveyEdit' of undefined

```
this.props.surveyEdit
```

this is the object I fetched from the database and I was hoping to use it to provide initial values to the field. I also couldn't see previous value on screen while I was trying.

Anyone have better idea? I am pretty sure there must be a way to do it, I just can't seem to comprehend how to implement it.

Thank you in advance as always!

Comment: looks like your mapStateToProps function doesnot have any effect on the code. state object is not getting assigned to props here.

Comment: I think `mapStateToProps` makes `this.props.surveyEdit` available to apply the initial values. So you are saying I should put more values in the function? like this? `title: state.surveyEdit.title`

Comment: this.props.surveyEdit will contain value only if it receives value from state.surveyEdit. This assignment happens in function mapStateToProps. you have to verify if this assignment  works or not.

Comment: `this.props.surveyEdit` does return the values that I needed, so the function works as the way I want, however, I am not sure how to implement the local state through `this.props.surveyEdit`

Comment: @Ilads show the code for `SurveyField` and `formFields` please